# Why cant i swap 2 numbers using static variables if static variables have only one copy stored for the whole part of the program?

Tags: c++, static, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

If static variables has only one copy for the program. So why is it not possible to swap 2 numbers using another function?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

void swap(int, int);

int main()
{
    static int a = 1;
    static int b = 2;
    swap(a, b);
    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl << "b = " << b << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}

void swap(int a,int b)
{
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl << "b = " << b << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That's not how parameters work.

Comment: Read about passing parameters by value vs by reference in your favorite C++ textbook. Your `swap` is a no-op (apart from printing a line of text). `static` is a red herring, it has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: The STL already has a [`std::swap()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) algorithm for swapping integers. You should use it, there is no need to write your own.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The STL did not use a namespace `std` to my knowledge. The C++ standard library does, though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Everything in the STL (Standard Template Library) and Standard Library are in the `std` namespace in C++.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Orly? TIL. Too bad they reused the namespace name for the stdlib. Rather defeats the purpose of namespaces.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why shouldn't they have used the same namespace? It works fine, it doesn't conflict with anything.  It is reserved so nobody else can use it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Perhaps review the purpose of namespaces. Re-using someone else's namespace is not "fine".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know what namespaces are and how they are used. What are you talking about, "someone else's namespace"? The STL and SL are managed by the same C++ standards committee. It is THEIR namespace being used for everything that they standardize. But whatever.  This is off-topic for this question, so I'm done commenting on this.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: _"The STL and SL are managed by the same C++ standards committee."_ False. The STL was written by SGI before a C++ standards committee existed. Said committee brought in parts of those brilliant ideas to form the basis for the new C++ Standard Library. According to you, both teams used the namespace `std` and both libraries as a result share a namespace name, which is ungood. But I'm sure that in reality you know this already as it is fairly fundamental C++ history!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the 'swap' function is taking parameters as pass by value, copies of the variables are passed to the swap function which will only swap its local variables 'a' and 'b' (passed as parameter) not the static ones passed from main.

Swap should be taking parameters as references like below.

```
#include <iostream>

void swap(int&, int&);

int main()
{
    static int a = 1;
    static int b = 2;
    swap(a, b);
    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl << "b = " << b << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}

void swap(int &a,int &b)
{
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl << "b = " << b << std::endl;
}
```

Please note that static variable defined in a function pertains its value in the subsequent calls of the function in which it is declared.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are passing arguments by value and not by address(reference). Your function is working on a copy of a and a copy of b - not the original values. You could try this(notice the & in the function prototype and function definition arguments)

```
void swap(int &, int &);

void swap(int& a, int& b)
{
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl << "b = " << b << std::endl;
}
```